# How to add a tick mark based on a counter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, counter

I'm making a simple game in HTML/Javascript where everytime a button or hyperlink gets pressed it adds 1 to a counter

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
function countClicks() {
 count = count + 1;
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = count;
}
</script>
```

My question is is there a way to also add a tick (Ascii #10004) equal to the number in the counter. I'm sure this is an easy solve but I've never really used Javascript and this seems the easiest language to do this all in. I appreciate any help given

Comment: Does this helps.. http://jsfiddle.net/oL83m567/

Comment: Do you mean you want to add 2 ticks when the counter is 2, 3 ticks when it's 3 etc?

Comment: Sorry should have said yes I would like it to show 2 ticks when count=2 and 3 when count=3 etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTML decimal: `&#9745;`

Just replace the code:

```
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = count;
```

with the following code:

```
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "&#9745 "+count;
```

Or you can use:

```
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "&#10004 "+count;
```

**The result will be like this:**

✔ 5

*here **5** is your count.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You even don't need a loop to concatenate ticks.

[see jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qeyraamr/1/)

```
var count = 5; // count is already 5 for demo purpose
function countClicks() {
    count = count + 1;
    var ticks = Array(count+1).join("&#10004;");
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = count+' '+ticks;
}

countClicks(); # 6 ✔✔✔✔✔✔
```

Comment: How easy would it be to remove a tick, I tried using var ticks = Array(count-1).shift("&#10004;"); but it says undefined

Comment: this Q/A is completed, if you have an other question please post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the String.fromCharCode to convert ascii code to character.
Example to display continuos ticks equal to number of count:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
function countClicks() {
    count = count + 1;
    var res = String.fromCharCode(10004);
    var output = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       output += res+" ";
    }
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = output;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to ADD another tick every time the thing is pressed? I would do it like this:

```
var count = 0;
function countClicks() {
 count = count + 1;
 document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML + '&#10004';
}
```

Or, slightly more efficiently:

```
var p2, count = 0;
function countClicks() {
 count = count + 1;
 p2 = document.getElementById("p2");

 p2.innerHTML = p2.innerHTML + '&#10004';
}
```

In that case, count becomes unnecessary, unless you need it for something else.

Answer (score 0):

This will do :

http://jsfiddle.net/oL83m567/1/

```
var count = 0;

function countClicks() {
  count = count + 1;
  var tick='';
  for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
    tick+= '&#x2714';
  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = count + tick;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for doing it with an array. Advantage of this is that you have the ticks stored as elements in the array and can manipulate them later e.g. change a chosen tick to a cross or have a button which removes a tick. Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ticks=new Array();
function countClicks() {
     ticks[ticks.length]="&#10004;";
     document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = ticks.join("");
}
</script>
```